# How to determine your default remote git repository?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

How can I see the default remote repository set on my Pycharm? 
I want to know when I type `git push` without specifying the repository name, which of my remote repository is going to be updated, assuming that I have added multiple remote repository with different alias names.

Comment: Are you looking for `git merge`?

Comment: It seems that you're asking two questions in the same post. It's better to separate two unrelated questions into two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

For viewing the default upstream repository you can use `git config --edit`.

This shows you how your git repository is set up.

Under the branch you want to check the remote of, there is a line: `remote = example`. Look for the remote name in that file and you can find out where everything will be sent/pulled from.

Comment: I do not want to change my default repository. I want to see what is my default repository. It is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question, it depends mainly on the setting of your remote repository.

On some third-party websites like github or bitbucket, you can set some branches as "*protected*", meaning that any push will be rejected on them, forcing anyone to use pull requests to merge anything in.

Out of this constraint, you can push to any branch, master or not. In this case, you indeed merge locally then push to remote.

Answer (score 0):

#### BEST: git push/pull --dry-run -v

A little bit messy, but most likely to actually be the answer to the question "What is the default remote repository?"

```
$>  git push --dry-run -v
Pushing to REMOTE-URL-OR-PATH
To REMOTE-URL-OR-PATH
 = [up to date]        master -> master
Everything up-to-date

$>  git pull --dry-run -v
From REMOTE-URL-OR-PATH
 = [up to date]  master       -> remote_repo/master
 = [up to date]  other-branch -> remote_repo/remote-name-for-branch
```

##### Almost as good: git branch -vv & git remote show <remote>

`git branch -vv` and `git remote show <remote>` are almost answers to the question "How do I determine the default remote repository?"

The output of `git branch -vv` may look like:

```
* master         41af0b6f [remote_repo/master]  commit message
  other-branch   1d9eb2e6 [remote_repo/branch-name-on-remote] blah blah
```

You can find the remote URLs or paths from `git remote -v`.

Unfortunately, `git branch -vv` does not tell you if you have separate defaults for pushing and fetch/pulling.

`git remote show <remote>` provides a lot more info, including push/pull distinction - but AFAICT it only handles one <remote> at a time, so you might have to iterate over all the remotes in your repo. See below for example output.

While you can try reading your `REPO/.git/config` or `git config --edit` -- it may be good enough for simple repos -- but in general there are so many different options and default combinations that it will make your eyeballs bleed.

#### TL;DR - i.e. excessive detail required because AFAIK there is no perfect answer

Late answer, as I had the same question.  Parts  of what might be a BKM (best known method), or at least a reasonably good way of answering this question  are scattered all over the place in stack overflow and many different websites. Many of these scattered parts are incorrect,  answering  questions like "how do I change the  default remote repository?"  rather than the question here " how do I tell  what the default  remote repository is?".    it also appears that  there has been considerable evolution  in this regard, new options added to various git commands.  it is quite possible that this is a duplicate  or has been answered elsewhere on StackExchange -  but this was the most  concise question I found in this regard.

First: git's concept of "default remote" is really per branch,  not per repository. (Although there are some ways of configuring git so that all branches in cloned repositories have the same default after the value is set. Also remote.pushDefault, etc.)

##### Read git config yourself :-(

So you can always look at your git config file, e.g. via "git config --edit" or manually by editing YOUR-GIT-REPO-ROOT/config, looking for stuff like

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = some_repo
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "some_repo"]
    url = ...
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/some_repo/*
```

However, it is made a little bit harder because  people frequently want to have different defaults for pulling and pushing in any particular branch. So you might see entries like in the config file.

```
[remote "<name>"]
        url = <URL>
        pushurl = <pushurl>
        push = <refspec>
        fetch = <refspec>
```

or set such options via refspecs like

```
remote.<branch>.pushDefault

branch.<name>.remote <-- remote.pushDefault --> <name>.pushRemote. 

branch.<name>.pushRemote --overrides--> branch.<name>.remote and remote.pushDefault 

branch.<name>.merge ---> branch.<name>.remote
```

and  if you don't find the above, or sometimes if you do, the special remote name "origin"  may or may not be used to determine where you will push or pull from.

BTW, although there are config options like pushDefault and pushurl, there are not really options like pullDefault.  Since pulls are really git fetch followed by a merge, look for *fetch* options... if you really want to chase it all down by hand.

Aargh!!! IIRC it was the bzr developer who said  something like "git makes my eyeballs bleed".

Anyway:  while you *can*  try reading your configuration,  if several or many of the above configuration options are in use it can be quite difficult to determine exactly where your pushes and pulls will go to  by default.   Although  most repositories will only have a restricted configuration, it is easy for a  long-lived repository to accumulate craft that makes it difficult.   IMHO the best way to determine where your pushes and pulls go is to run code on an actual computer, not simulate it in your head.

##### git branch -vv - better, but does not understand push/pull separation

The closest I have come  to actually  have an automatic way to determine  where the default pushes and pulls go to for a particular branch is `git branch -vv` whose documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch says:

> -v
> -vv
> --verbose
>
> When in list mode, show sha1 and commit subject line for each head,
> along with relationship to upstream branch (if any). If given twice,
> print the path of the linked worktree (if any) and the name of the
> upstream branch, as well (see also `git remote show <remote>`). ....

The output of `git branch -vv` may look like:

```
* master         41af0b6f [remote_repo/master]  commit message
  other-branch   1d9eb2e6 [remote_repo/branch-name-on-remote] blah blah
```

where remote_repo  is the local name for the remote repository name (duh),  frequently "origin"  but possibly something else.

And you can map the local name for the remote repository to its URL or filesystem pathname by `git remote -v`

Unfortunately, this version of `git branch -vv` only knows about "the name of the upstream branch", and does not handle cases where push/pull/?? have different defaults.

##### git remote show <remote> - better, but maps wrong way

`git remote show <remote>` provides a lot more info, including push/pull distinction - but AFAICT it only handles one <remote> at a time, so you might have to iterate over all the remotes in your repo.

```
* remote onedrive_repo
  Fetch URL: ...
  Push  URL: ...
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    master        tracked
    some-other    tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    master           merges with remote master
    other-branch     merges with remote branch_name_on_remote
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    master           pushes to master                  (up to date)
    other-branch     pushes to branch_name_on_remote
```

##### --dry-run and --verbose options are your friends

#### BEST: git push/pull --dry-run -v

I almost forgot - probably the best approach, if you only want to ask the question for a single branch. Likely to actually be correct.

```
$>  git push --dry-run -v
Pushing to REMOTE-URL-OR-PATH
To REMOTE-URL-OR-PATH
 = [up to date]        master -> master
Everything up-to-date

$>  git pull --dry-run -v
From REMOTE-URL-OR-PATH
 = [up to date]  master       -> remote_repo/master
 = [up to date]  other-branch -> remote_repo/remote-name-for-branch
```

##### Are we done yet? No... submodules

Submodules add yet another filip to this problem. I won't go into it here. --dry-run --verbose is again your friend.